# Common Signing tool for java mobiles

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, signing, samsung-mobile

Can anyone tell me what is the common signing tools used by almost all java mobile vendors like Samsung, Sony, Nokia, Micromax, Moto and so on.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,  [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/sun-java/index.html), [Verisign](https://www.verisign.com/code-signing/sun-java/index.html?sl=productdetails) and [Java verified](http://javaverified.com/) supports most of the devices. But all are cost. Once I was chatted with Thawte and Verisign technical team for this purpose. They said most of the devices will support after signing the application. But they don't have supported mobile model list. Better you can go with Thawte.