# how to send the http request with the help of certificate in res folder of the project in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, https, mobile-application, nokia-s40

Im developing a mobile app in j2me.In that i send a https request to the server which had self signed.My target mobile is "Nokia c2 00".Here i cannto put the server's certificate into mobile.
  Im added the server's certificate (the file is keystore.cert) in the "res" folder of my project.
  Please help me to send a https request to the server and get response with the help of the certificate (keystore.cert) in the "res" folder.Please give me ur valuable idea.Its very urgen please help me.

Comment: Kindly visit the following [link][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164122/j2me-midlet-self-signed-certificate/8164404#8164404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No server certificates not valid and supported in the Mobile. You have to signing the your mobile application separately. But It will be cost. The Cost will be vary from [providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649215/common-signing-tool-for-java-mobiles/6649490#6649490).