# Is it a good idea to use and set a value for the MIDlet-Permissions-Opt and/or MIDlet-Permissions attributes to auto-sign a MIDlet?

Tags: java-me, midp, signing, midlet

There is the `MIDlet-Permissions` and `MIDlet-Permissions-Opt` attributes that can be set in the jad file. Can we use them to auto-sign a MIDlet ?

Comment: What is auto signed MIDlet? I cant understand that. :-/

Comment: It is making the app not showing the questions when using `FileConnection` for example.

Comment: Have you sign your mobile application?

Comment: I want to avoid paying money to buy signing. So I am looking for ways to autosign the app. So for your question : the app is not signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, There is **no** way to signing your mobile application manually. Its not possible in Java ME development. You have to sign your mobile application from some [3rd party providers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649215/common-signing-tool-for-java-mobiles/6649490#6649490) But it will be cost and look on this article for know about [MIDlet permissions.](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/20798)